# Jquery files upload(blueimp) - files uploading order by id

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, jquery-ui, file-upload

I am using jquery files upload plugin [blueimp](https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/)  in my project. The question is when I finished uploading my multiple files, they will sort out automatically by files "Name" when I refresh the page. I tried to modify index.php in server folder with ORDER BY id (SQL) but it didn't work.

I went google but it only shows some solutions like sequentialUploads or prependFiles to set to True, that's Not my actually looking for.

Comment: After sort order by id, I mean it will set my newest upload file in the top and oldest upload file in the bottom.

Answer (score 0):

I used code below..
you can make new folder from id has submitted and image will be upload insert into new folder created.
try..

```
$result=mysql_query("SELECT * FROM ps1_ba  order by id desc limit 1");
                    $row =mysql_fetch_array($result);
                    $id_ba="".$row['id']."";

$newfolder = dirname($this->get_server_var('SCRIPT_FILENAME')).'/'.'/files/'.$id.'/';
if(!is_dir($newfolder)){
    mkdir($newfolder, 0777);
```

Comment: That might be a solution after a fashion. I have lots of images can not create a folder for each of them.. But thanks!